# Cannot fill my html table with json result

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fill one of my table with json result from controller. I check out `console.log(result);` it has the data which I am passing from controller

Here is my controller code

```
        Dim result As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection()
        Do While rst.Read
            result.Add(New With {.batch = rst!batch_no, .expiry = rst!expiry_date, .qty = rst!bal_qty, .mrp = rst!mrp, .prchasedate = rst!purchase_date})
        Loop
        Return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Here is the script I am using

```
    $('#MedicineID').blur(function () {
        //Perform your AJAX call to the Controller Action
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("FillBatchTable", "MedicinePurchase")",
            dataType: "json",
            data: document.getElementById("MedicineID").value,
            success: function (result) {
                var row = "";
                $.each(result, function () {
                    row += "<td>" + result.batch + "</td>" + "<td>" + result.expiry + "</td>" + "<td>" + result.qty + "</td>" + "<td>" + result.mrp + "</td>" + "<td>" + result.prchasedate + "</td>";
                });
                $("#BatchNoDetailsBody").html(row);
                console.log(result);
                //Your success message
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error" + result);
                //Your error message
            }
        });
    });
```

I am getting data in my javascript console

```
Array[1]
0: Object
batch: "L14382"
expiry: "/Date(1451500200000)/"
mrp: 85
prchasedate: "/Date(1393353000000)/"
qty: 7
```

And in view time I am getting my table field with an undefined value its just show me undefine in each row

And another issue is I cant pass value of MedicineID to controller

Comment: You need to show the signature of the method your posting to. Assuming its accepts parameter `(int ID)` then to pass the value it needs to be `data:  { ID: document.getElementById("MedicineID").value },` (although it better t use `data: { ID: $(this).val() },` rather that searching the DOM again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for not passing the value to the controller, you need to pass a key/value pair so assuming the parameter of your controller is

```
public JsonResult FillBatchTable(int ID)
```

then the ajax `data` option needs to be

```
data: { ID: document.getElementById("MedicineID").value },
```

or better (to avoid traversing the DOM again)

```
data: { ID: $(this).val() },
```

As for getting undefined, the value of `result` is an array of objects and an array does not contain properties named `batch`, `expiry` etc. You need to access each item in the array

```
success: function (result) {
  var table = $("#BatchNoDetailsBody");
  $.each(result, function (index, item) {
    var row = $('</tr>');
    row.append($('</td>').text(item.batch));
    row.append($('</td>').text(item.expiry));
    row.append($('</td>').text(item.qty));
    row.append($('</td>').text(item.mrp));
    row.append($('</td>').text(item.prchasedate));
    table.append(row);
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly IMO this is a bad way of doing a data table, look into SlickGrids, DataTables or any other jQuery Table library...

The issue is on this line

```
row += "<td>" + result.batch + "</td>" + "<td>" + result.expiry + "</td>" + "<td>" + result.qty + "</td>" + "<td>" + result.mrp + "</td>" + "<td>" + result.prchasedate + "</td>";
```

it should be

```
row += "<tr><td>" + result.batch + "</td>" + "<td>" + result.expiry + "</td>" + "<td>" + result.qty + "</td>" + "<td>" + result.mrp + "</td>" + "<td>" + result.prchasedate + "</td></tr>";
```

You see I added `<tr>` because you are doing a row...then you'd need to inject the `row` string into a `<table>`.  Provide your html if you want a demo with jsFiddle.

**Note:** you might need to also look at the `result` in the `success` function of your `ajax` .NET uses `result.d` to hold the actual result a lot of the time (in ASP.NET not MVC.NET)

Comment: Adding <tr> </tr> doesnt help it still shoing me a row with undefined

Comment: @Snehal please put a breakpoint on the line `var row = "";` then look at result and see where the data is...

Comment: Why is this _"a bad way of doing a data table"_? It perfectly fine if you don't need the features provided by those plugin and certainly save a lot of overhead.